# Sending data between react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, react-apollo

Sorry for the long winded code snippet but could anybody help with the below. I'm trying to bring some data from another objecy into my mutation but when the form submits the data doesnt go with it, even though the correct values show in the form. If you look at the code below, you can see i've wrapped the mutation in a user query and used me.address etc to show the data.What am i doing wrong ...pulling my hair out here

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import User from './User';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import Router from 'next/router';
import Form from './styles/Form';
import Ghost from './styles/Ghost';
import Error from './ErrorMessage';

const Div = styled.div `
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
`;

const Container = styled.div `
    max-width: 1000px;
`;

const SINGLE_USER_QUERY = gql`
  query SINGLE_USER_QUERY($id: ID!) {
    user(where: { id: $id }) {
      id
      address
      lat
      lng
    }
  }
`;

const CREATE_JOB_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation CREATE_JOB_MUTATION(
    $name: String
    $address: String
    $email: String
    $description: String!
    $image: String!
    $cube: Int!
    $reqPickup: String
    $instructions: String!
    $feedback: String
    $lat: String
    $lng: String
    $pickup: DateTime
    $charges: Int
    $price: Int
  ) {
    createJob(
    name: $name
    address: $address
    email: $email
    description: $description
    image: $image
    cube: $cube
    reqPickup: $reqPickup
    instructions: $instructions
    feedback: $feedback
    lat: $lat
    lng: $lng
    pickup: $pickup
    charges: $charges
    price: $price
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;


class CreateJob extends Component {
    state = {
      name: '',
      address: '',
      email: '',
      description: '',
      image: '',
      cube: '',
      reqPickup: '',
      instructions: '',
      feedback: '',
      lat: '',
      lng: '',
      pickup: '',
      charges: '0',
      price: '0',
    };


    handleChange = (e) => {
      const { name, type, value } = e.target;
      const val = type === 'number' ? parseFloat(value) : value;
      this.setState({ [name]: val});
    };    

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log(this.state);
    };

    uploadFile = async e => {
      const files = e.target.files;
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('file', files[0]);
      data.append('upload_preset', 'sickfits');

      const res = await fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/wesbostutorial/image/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data,
      });
      const file = await res.json();
      this.setState({
        image: file.secure_url,
        largeImage: file.eager[0].secure_url,
      });
    };

    render() {
        return (


          <Div>
          <Container>
          <User>
      {({ data }) => {
        const me = data ? data.me : null
        return (
          <Mutation mutation={CREATE_JOB_MUTATION} variables={this.state}>
            {(createJob, { loading, error }) => (
          <Form
          data-test="form"
          onSubmit={async e => {
            // Stop the form from submitting
            e.preventDefault();
            // call the mutation
            console.log(this.state);
            this.setState({ address: me.address });
            const res = await createJob();
            // change them to the single job page
            console.log(res);
            Router.push({
              pathname: '/job',
              query: { id: res.data.createJob.id },
            });
          }}>
                <Error error={error} />
            <fieldset disabled={loading} aria-busy={loading}>

                <label htmlFor="description"> 
                    Describe your waste: Just a few words to describe the materials.
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    id="description"
                    name="description"
                    placeholder="eg: wood, bricks, old kitchen tops and a fridge"
                    required
                    value={this.state.description}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                    </label>

                    <label htmlFor="instructions"> 
                    Instructions: Any specific instructions such as desired collection time or access info.
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    id="instructions"
                    name="instructions"
                    placeholder="Instructions for the collection team"
                    required
                    value={this.state.instructions}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                    </label>


                    <label htmlFor="address"> 
                    Address:
                    <input
                    type="text"
                    id="address"
                    name="address"
                    required
                    defaultValue={me.address}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  />
                    </label>


                    <p
                    style={{
                        textAlign: 'center',
                      }}
                    >Click the submit button and we'll come back to you in just a few moments with a quote and collection time options</p>
                    <div
                     style={{
                        display: 'flex',
                        margin: 'auto',
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                      }}
                    >
                    <button
                    type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </Form>
            )}
            </Mutation>
            )
          }}
        </User>
            </Container>
          </Div>
        );
    }
}

export default CreateJob;
export { CREATE_JOB_MUTATION };
```

Comment: Did you console.log your statae to see if your state is filled with data?

Comment: console.log(this.state);
this.setState({ address: me.address });
The two above lines were from my de-bugging efforts. console.log to see what was in my state (null) and setstate to try and send the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `<User/>` contains query component and rendes children ... `data` will contain result (when data will arrive) you want to be stored in the state...

```
  {({ data }) => {
    // is data from query ready?
    const me = data ? data.me : null;
    // prevent looping (setState > rerendering)
    if( me && (me.address!=this.state.address) ) {
      setState( {address: me.address} )
    }
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={CREATE_JOB_MUTATION} 
        variables={this.state}
        onCompleted={(data)=>{
          console.log("mutated, result: ", data);
          // Router.push
        }}
      >
        {(createJob, { loading, error }) => (
```

**You should place this functionality (form+mutation) in separate component for managing state inside** (pass address as prop) **and more important not rerendering all of this structures/components.** Components are cheap in react ;)

As Józef stated it would be easier to 'compose' mutation input on call like:

```
 createJob({variables: { ...this.state, address: me.address} })
```

`await`-ing doesn't make sense as you should use `onCompleted` callback.

Answer (score -1):

```js
const res = await createJob();
```

Shouldn't you add param to `createJob` function?

In this case it would be `await createJob({variables: this.state});`

[well examples in docs tell so](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/mutations/)

Comment: I am not sure. Never used Mutation component before. But the docs do tell you can also pass variables as props like he has.

Comment: Variables may be provided as either a prop to the `Mutation` component, or a parameter to the `mutate` function, or both. If both are provided, they will be merged into a single `variables` object. This is true of both the `Mutation` component and the `useMutation` hook.